# Gradient in geom_ribbon

Tags: r, ggplot2, gradient

I have the following `ggplot2` code that plots the ribbon from the 3rd to the 97th quartile:

```
h <- ggplot(l, aes(x=age[limit]))
h <- h + geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=X3rd[limit], ymax=X97th[limit]), fill="gray80") 
h
```

The geom_ribbon [help page](http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/geom_ribbon.html) suggests that gradient, gradient2, etc are 'related scales' for fill for this geom. What I'm after is to have the ribbon light grey on the outside, to darker grey in the middle then lighter grey again on the outside, but I get the impression (and some google results strengthen this impression) that the gradients can't actually be applied to ribbon.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

geom_ribbon does not support gradient.
Instead, if I correctly understand what you want to do, then overlapping ribbons may be useful:

```
d <- data.frame(x=1:10, m=runif(10))
d <- transform(d, l1=m-1, l2=m-2, u1=m+1, u2=m+2)

ggplot(d, aes(x)) + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=l2, ymax=u2), fill="grey60") + 
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=l1, ymax=u1), fill="grey40")
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. This is what I had done in the mean time, still looks quite good as I have 5th/9th 10th/90th and 25th/75th percentile. I had read that you can try and use geom_tile to achieve the gradient affect but sounded very fiddly. Thanks for the confirmation.